# Dynamically load JavaScript with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, api, google-maps-api-3, xss

After over an hour of trying to get it to work I'm thinking it's because of cross domain policies, but I really thought this would work. I can't find a lot of info on it either. But, here is my issue. I have a site called http://mysite.com and then I include a 3rd party script (what im writing) and its at http://supercoolsite.com/api/script.js and this script needs to dynamically load the google maps api at: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false before it runs. Well, i figured this code would work:

```
function loadScript(filename,callback){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
  fileref.onload = callback();
  if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
  }
}

loadScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',function(){
  console.log('done loading');
  init();
});
```

But my response in my console is:

```
api.js:408 done loading
api.js:115 test
api.js:310 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

the "`test`" is at the top of the `init()`. So, it's loading the script, but it's not executing it, it seems. So, any ideas? If it is a cross site scripting issue my only method of fixing this i could think of is having a PHP script on our end that basically just sets the header to a text/javascript header and then `echo file_get_contents()` into a `googlemaps.php` file we host. About to try this as we speak, but, if possible, a way to do it with pure JS would be awesome.

P.S. I also tried adding jQuery, then doing `getScript()`, and it still didnt work

-- UPDATE --

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ycMCa/2/

You'll see that you get the error in your console:
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Despite that the `google` variable is global.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have a minor error:

```
fileref.onload = callback();
```

This will call `callback` immediately and assign its **return value** to `fileref.onload`.

It should be

```
fileref.onload = callback;
```

You also should add the handler before you set the source (just in case).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ycMCa/)